# Элементарные циклы в С

Tags: c

Привет, товарищи программисты. Каким образом, более удобно будет реализовать циклы для элементарных заданий? Типа подсчета цикла суммы.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что Вам нужно подсчитать. Какую сумму? Уточните, плиз.

Comment: Хм... ну вот к примеру такую http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=100223&thumb=1&d=1318445215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так такие вещи делать положено в цикле с for. Пример - подсчет суммы натуральных чисел от 1 до 10:

```
int i, s = 0;
for (i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
   s += i; 
}
```

Comment: Ну многие говорят что лучше в while... Но поверю умным людям)

Comment: Можно как хочешь. Подумай, как проще? В while прописывать все инкриментации, сравнения, выходы из цикла и т.д. или ограничиться одной строкой в for? И не факт, что while будет быстрее выполняться. Возможно, даже и нет...

Если ответ подошел. не забываем ставить плюсик.

Answer (score 5):

На "физическом" уровне разницы между разными типами циклов нет. У процессора нет инструкций for, while или do. Если утрировать, то процессор умеет только if и goto :-)

Более того - современные компиляторы код оптимизируют по различным параметрам и могут циклы разворачивать в линейный набор инструкций. Таким образом возможно ускорить выполнение программы, т.к. не будет лишних операций сравнения и перехода, но раздувается размер программы.

В качестве домашнего задания предлагаю написать один и тот же алгоритм с применением разных типов циклов.

Еще интересным занятием - является переписывание алгоритмов на рекурсивный лад. Например, можно вспомнить вычисление факториала. Его можно написать и как цикл, и как рекурсивные вызовы функции.

Comment: я бы не утверждал, что у процессоров нет инструкций for/while. Конечно, прям таких инструкций нет, но есть инструкции, которые заточены для них. Например есть префикс rep/repz который повторяет заданную инструкцию заданное кол-во раз. Или инструкция loop, которая использует регистр ecx (или cx, или какой подходит по разрядности) как счетчик.
Поэтому, в многих случаях, если сильно не хитрить, оптимизируя, то компилятор может распознать цикл и очень удачно заменить на оптимальный набор инструкций.

Comment: Только не забывайте, без включения режима оптимизации, компилятор ничего из описанного выше делать не будет. Для gcc пишите gcc -O3 myprog.c -o myprog

Для получения ассемблерного кода задайте флаг -S, например gcc -S -O3 myprog.c
создаст файл myprog.s , содержащий оптимизированный код на ассемблере (его интересно изучать).